# Quick Sort Time Complexity Best Case Input

Tags: algorithm, sorting, input, time-complexity, quicksort

I have to find time complexity of quick sort for BEST CASE INPUT in a c program & i have selected the last element of array as pivot.
Now i know what input values i have to enter for best case, i.e., keep 1st middle element at the last place(pivot) & next pivot should be the next middle element.
But i have to generate this kind of best case input array of very big sizes like 1000, 5000, 100000.., for quick sort.
I can code, but can anyone please help me understand how to generate that kind of best case input array for quick sort with last pivot, using c programming.
I just need the logic like how to generate that kind of array using c programming.

Comment: The question doesn't specify if Lomuto or Hoare partition type schemes are used. Lomuto would be simpler, since the pivot is put in place and excluded when making recursive calls. With Hoare partition scheme, the pivot element can end up anywhere and will be included in either the left or right sub-partition at each step.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to do a divide & conquer approach akin to quicksort itself. Do it with a function that given a range of indices in the output:

1. generates the first-half partition by recursively calling itself
2. generates the second-half partition by recursively calling itself
3. inserts the pivot value after the second-half partition.

One thing to note is that since you are just generating output not sorting anything, you don't actually have to have any values as input -- you can just represent ranges logically as a start value at some index in the array and a count.

Some C# code is below; this is untested -- don't look if you want to do this yourself.

```
static int[] GenerateBestCaseQuickSort(int n)
{
    var ary = new int[n];
    GenerateBestCaseQuickSortAux(ary, 0, n, 1);
    return ary;
}

static void GenerateBestCaseQuickSortAux(int[] ary, int start_index, int count, int start_value)
{
    if (count == 0)
        return;

    if (count == 1)
    {
        ary[start_index] = start_value;
        return;
    }

    int partition1_count = count / 2;
    int partition2_count = count - partition1_count - 1; // need to save a spot for the pivot so -1...
    int pivot_value_index = start_index + partition1_count;
    int pivot_value = start_value + partition1_count;

    GenerateBestCaseQuickSort(ary, start_index, partition1_count, start_value);
    GenerateBestCaseQuickSort(ary, pivot_value_index, partition2_count, pivot_value+1);
    ary[start_index + count - 1] = pivot_value;
}
```